# Group such that factors in any product-decomposition are reducible

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

**Motivation.** Let us call a group $G = (G,\cdot)$ *(product-)reducible* if there are groups $H_1, H_2$, each having more than $1$ element, with $G \cong H_1\times H_2$. Otherwise, $G$ is said to be *irreducible*. If $G$ is finite, then $G$ is isomorphic to a product of irreducible groups. This is because in the finite case, proper subgroups of a group have strictly smaller cardinality, so you can't have infinitely descending chains of proper subgroups. - In the infinite case, things may look different.

**Infinite case.** Is there an infinite group $G$ such that whenever $\kappa \geq 0$ is a cardinal and $G_\alpha$ are non-trivial groups for $\alpha\in\kappa$ such that $G \cong \prod_{\alpha\in\kappa}G_\alpha$, then for all $\alpha\in\kappa$, the group $G_\alpha$ is reducible?

Comment: The standard terminology is decomposable and indecomposable.

Comment: You need to assume that each $G_\alpha$ is nontrivial. (Also, by convention, the trivial group is not indecomposable.)

Comment: Right @YCor, will include this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is: is there an infinite group
whose nontrivial direct factors are all directly decomposable?
The answer is 'Yes'.
First I will explain why the answer is 'Yes'
to the analogous question for Boolean algebras (BAs).

**Claim 1.**
The following are equivalent for a nontrivial BA $B$:

1. $B$ has an indecomposable direct factor.
2. $B$ has a direct factor of size $2$.
3. $B$ has an atom.

**Reasoning.**
For the equivalence of (1) and (2),
a nontrivial BA is indecomposable
if and only if it has size $2$.
(For any BA $C$ of more then $2$ elements,
if $a\in C-\{0,1\}$,
then the complementary ideals $(a)$ and $(\neg a)$
are factor ideals for a nontrivial direct decomposition.)

For (2)$\Rightarrow$(3),
if $B$ has a direct factor of size $2$, then
we may assume that $B=C\times D$ where $|C|=2$,
and when this happens $a=(1,0)\in C\times D = B$ is an atom.
For (3)$\Rightarrow$(2),
if $a\in B$
is an atom, then the complementary ideals $(a)$ and $(\neg a)$
are factor ideals for a direct decomposition,
where $B/(\neg a)$ has size $2$.
\\\

This is enough to show that any atomless BA has the property
that no nontrivial direct factor is directly indecomposable.
One can repackage this so that it is a statement about groups.

**Claim 2.**
If $A$ is a finite, simple, nonabelian group
and $B$ is an atomless BA, then the group
that is the Boolean power
$A[B]^*$ has the property
that no nontrivial direct factor is directly indecomposable.

[The Boolean power $A[B]^*$ is the subalgebra of the direct
power $A^{B^*}$ (where $B^*$ is the Stone space of $B$)
whose elements $f\in A^{B^*}$ are the continuous
functions $f\colon B^*\to A$ where $A$ is equipped
with the discrete topology.]

**Reasoning.**
The Maurer-Rhodes Theorem yields that if $A$
is a finite, simple, nonabelian group and $A_A$
is the expansion of $A$ by all constants, then
$A_A$ is a primal algebra. Saying that $A_A$
is primal means that it is finite and every finitary operation
$g\colon (A_A)^n\to A_A$ is a term operation of $A_A$.
The work of T. K. Hu shows that any variety
generated by a primal algebra $P$
is categorically equivalent to the variety of Boolean algebras.
The equivalence is the composition of two dualities:
Stone duality,  $B\mapsto B^*$, composed with the
Boolean power functor $B^*\mapsto P[B]^*$.
In particular, this equivalence guarantees
that if $B$ is any BA and $P$ is any primal
algebra, then $B$ and $P[B]^*$ have isomorphic congruence lattices,
and under this isomorphism the factor congruences will correspond.
Thus, if $B$ is atomless and $P$ is the primal algebra $A_A$,
then $B$ and $(A_A)[B]^*$ have isomorphic congruence lattices
and corresponding direct decompositions.

Now pass from $A_A$ to $A$ by dropping the constants that were added.
This has some effect: the reduct $A$ of $A_A$ is no longer primal,
the algebra $A[B]^*$ has richer subalgebra structure than $(A_A)[B]^*$, etc.
But the congruences of
$(A_A)[B]^*$ and $A[B]^*$
are the same, and the factor congruences are the same.
This is enough to establish the claim. \\\

Comment: Your "detour" with atomless Boolean algebras is beautiful!

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen the gist of the proof lies in the Maurer-Rhodes theorem.

Answer (score 6):

$\DeclareMathOperator\supp{supp}$Let $X$ be a Cantor space, and let $S$ be a nonabelian simple group (or more generally a nontrivial group in which every nontrivial conjugacy class has a trivial centralizer, e.g., the symmetric group $S_n$ for $n\ge 5$). Let $G=C(X,S)$ be the group of continuous functions $C\to S$ ($S$ being viewed as discrete group).

(Note that if $S$ is countable, so is $G$.)

I claim that every nontrivial direct factor of $G$ is isomorphic to $G$ (and hence decomposable). To see this, I check that every direct product decomposition $G=A\times B$ is induced by a finite clopen partition of the Cantor set, i.e., for some clopen partition $X=Y\sqcup Z$, one has $A=C(Y,S)$ and $B=C(Z,S)$. (Thus, $G$ is nontrivial, decomposable, and every nontrivial direct factor of $G$ is isomorphic to $G$ and hence decomposable as well.)

Lemma (immediate — this is where the assumption on $S$ is used): *for $g\in G_S$, the centralizer of the conjugacy class $c_g$ of $g$ is the set of $h$ with support disjoint from $g$.*

Consider the supports of elements of $A\cup B$. They form a clopen covering of $K$. By compactness, one can extract a finite covering. Noting that supports of elements of $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (by the lemma), we obtain a finite covering of $X$ of the form $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}\supp(a_i)\sqcup \bigcup_{j\in J}\supp(b_j)$, with $a_i\in A$, $b_j\in B$, and $I$, $J$ finite. Write $Y=\bigcup_{i\in I}\supp(a_i)$, $Z=\bigcup_{j\in J}\supp(b_j)$. If $b\in B$, then for every $i$, $b$ centralizes $c_{a_i}$, and hence, by the lemma, $\supp(b)\cap\supp(a_i)$ is empty. Since this holds for all $i$, $\supp(b)\subseteq Z$. Similarly $\supp(a)\subseteq Y$ for all $a\in A$. Hence $A\subseteq C(Y,S)$ and $B\subseteq C(Z,S)$. Since $G=A\times B$, these have to be equalities: $A=C(Y,S)$ and $B= C(Z,S)$.

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful answer. I had a hard time choosing which one to accept. Might write a meta.mathoverflow question on that (if there is not any yet).

Comment: No problem, Keith Kearnes shot first (it was hard for me to read his answer but it might just be the same example, hidden behind more logic language). The "1 accepted answer only" fact is well-admitted on StackOverflow, so there's probably no point in discussing it on meta.

Answer (score 3):

There are also abelian examples (these are called superdecomposable abelian groups).

For example, by Theorem 5.1 of

*Corner, A. L. S.*, [**Every countable reduced torsion-free ring is an endomorphism ring**](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/s3-13.1.687), Proc. Lond. Math. Soc., III. Ser. 13, 687-710 (1963). [ZBL0116.02403](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0116.02403).

there is a countable torsion-free example.

Comment: It's depressing that LMS still puts its 60-year-old papers behind a paywall...